# Ansible & MySQL Remote Permissions

Tags: mysql, remote-access, ansible

I seem to be running into a problem with Ansible and creating a user and setting remote permissions for it.  I'm trying to create a user that accesses a specific database server remotely through a separate API server.

`mysql_user: login_user=root login_password=password name=sampleUser password=password priv=sampleDatabase.'192.168.33.8':ALL state=present`

All things work when I do `...priv=sampleDatabase.*:All...`

The error Ansible throws in the console seems to get the formatting off, it looks like this:

`_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.168.33.8 TO 'sampleDatabase'@'localhost'' at line 1")`

I can confirm doing the same equal functions manually in the mysql console without Ansible.

Comment: this may not help, but try doublequoting the payload of "prov".

Answer (score 2):

I was getting similar issues with this module, the full command I use was

```
- name: Create mysql user
  mysql_user: 
    login_password={{ root_mysql_password }}
    name={{ mysql_user }} 
    password={{ mysql_password }} 
    priv={{ mysql_db }}.*:ALL
    host={{ remote_host_ip }}
```

I also used in my vars file

`remote_host_ip: %`

But this could be a security hole

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish similar results by adding `host:` entry to the IP I wanted only access from.

Comment: @user393219 would you please provide an example