# How to use "--bind-address=ip_address" with ansible mysql_user module

Tags: mysql, ansible

I have multiple interfaces in my application nodes, how to tell ansible mysql_user module to bind the connection on user specified (eth0/eth1... OR ip address ?)interface ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666949/ansible-mysql-remote-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
- name: Create user
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    name: "your-user"
    host: "ip-goes-here"
    state: present
```

Comment: i am looking to use the ip address like "mysql --bind-address=<ip_of_local_host_interface> -uroot -p -h <database server ip>